# I need a rescue recovery code for 2019/04/02 Asus transformer

Tags: password-recovery, recovery

I need a rescue recovery code for 2019/04/02. I haven't tried anything else except try to find where I can generate these codes?

Answer (score 0):

https://bios-pw.org/ generates a working password using the date displayed on the recovery password screen